# Motion on inclined plane

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram

What has to be the conditions for an object of mass $m$ to move down an inclined plane with **uniform velocity** in terms of the forces acting in different directions on the object?

Comment: DON'T USE CAPITAL LETTERS IN YOUR TITLE & NEITHER IN THE BODY!! These rather increase the vagueness & nothing else; if the words need to be emphasized, either make them __bold__ or _italicise_ them. What enjoyment do these people get from _caps_; I don't know:\

Comment: Indeed, why make the title all capital when no other questions on the site do this. It's confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take simple case of frictionless inclined plane, you need to provide
opposite force of magnitude $mg\cos\theta$ to the mass where $mg$ is weight and $\theta$ is angle made by inclined plane with the ground. Normal reaction is balanced by $mg\sin\theta$.

When friction is involved, again opposite force of magnitude $\mu_sN$ or $\mu_kN$
need to be added depending on whether it is static/kinetic friction.